# IPython: executing a function after ctrl+d keypress

Tags: python, ipython

I have right now a `django` project and I like to test and check things by executing `./manage.py shell` which spawns an `ipython` shell.

In some projects I have a threads that run in the background and do stuff. Sometimes, while in a `ipython` session, I need to start one of these threads. I usually forget to `join()` the thread **before** I press `ctrl+d` to exit the shell, at which point `ipython` blocks.

I tried registering a cleanup method with `atexit.register` but that didn't work because it is called too late.

```
import time
import atexit
from threading import Thread


def test():
    for x in xrange(30):
        print "x = %s" % x 
        time.sleep(1)

th = Thread(target = test)

def stop():
    global th
    print "ATEXIT: stop"
    if th.is_alive():
        th.join()

atexit.register(stop)
```

I put that in a file `test.py`

```
$ ipython
In [1]: %run "test.py"

In [2]: ctrl+d pressed                                                                                                                                                      
ATEXIT: stop
```

As you can see the function registered with `atexit` was executed. However, if I start the thread:

```
$ ipython
In [1]: %run "test.py"

In [2]: th.start()
x = 0
x = 1
....
In [3]: ctrl+d pressed 
x = 2
x = 3
.....
x = 29
ATEXIT: stop
```

So, what I need is a way of executing `stop()` after I press `ctrl+d`. I've found this thread [Override ipython exit function - or add hooks in to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39499748/override-ipython-exit-function-or-add-hooks-in-to-it#39499913) but I don't know how to install a hook from an interactive shell and besides, it seems that the hook has been deprecated. How can I execute code after pressing `ctrl+d`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18114560/python-catch-ctrl-c-command-prompt-really-want-to-quit-y-n-resume-executi This probably answers your question.

Comment: @Douglas: I'll take a closer look later, thanks.

Comment: @Douglas: not exactly what I'm looking for. I want to execute some code when I press `ctrl+d` *inside* the `ipython` session, so that I can `join()` my threads.

Answer (score 0):

I found the (possible) answer here: [How can I capture 'Ctrl-D' in python interactive console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17650754/how-can-i-capture-ctrl-d-in-python-interactive-console)

I don't know if it's different with iPython, but Ctrl-D should raise an EOFError.  Try this code:

```
try:
    raw_input()
except EOFError:
    pass
```

If this does not work with iPython, please tell me.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a closer look at it when I get home from work.